# Node.js - controlling the size of a POST request

Tags: http, node.js, post

I have a program in Node.JS, using Express. When I do a POST request to this program, what is the maximum accepted size for the data in the request? Is there any way to set this size?

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Express, you can use the limit middleware: http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-limit.html

If you are interested in it's implementation, it does something like this:

```
// limit
req.on('data', function(chunk){
  received += chunk.length;
  if (received > bytes) deny();
});
```

For more details check the code on github: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/limit.js

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to expand the size of the accepted POST request. The content I'm sending to the node program appears to be bigger than the accepted limit, and it's being truncated.

Comment: Unless you are using another middleware that limits the post size, I am not aware of such a limitation.